# Doing math with a CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a problem with calculating some values that are in a CSV file using C#.

I have trouble finding any example of this on Google.

```
61,0000000000005,00000001,1,00002999,00002999,61,00,0,T,006158932
61,0000000000005,00000001,1,00002999,00002999,30,00,0,T,014026734
61,0000000000030,00000001,1,00003499,00003499,29,01,0,T,009033154
61,0000000000049,00000001,1,00002999,00002999,30,01,0,T,014026574
61,0000000000049,00000003,1,00002999,00008997,05,01,0,T,008111854
61,0000000000049,00000001,1,00002999,00002999,03,01,0,T,004211647
61,0000000000049,00000001,1,00002999,00002999,11,01,0,T,001058055
61,0000000000056,00000002,1,00000999,00001998,30,01,0,T,014026627
61,0000000000056,00000001,1,00000999,00000999,30,01,0,T,014026627
61,0000000000056,00000001,1,00000999,00000999,05,01,0,T,008111875
61,0000000000056,00000001,1,00000999,00000999,03,01,0,T,004211642
61,0000000000056,00000001,1,00000999,00000999,06,01,0,T,011133513
61,0000000000058,00000001,1,00001499,00001499,30,01,0,T,014026652
61,0000000000058,00000001,1,00001499,00001499,11,01,0,T,001057984
61,0000000000058,00000001,1,00001499,00001499,11,01,0,T,001058068
61,0000000000058,00000001,1,00001499,00001499,11,01,0,T,001058068
61,0000000000058,00000001,1,00001499,00001499,16,01,0,T,003205784
61,0000000000058,00000001,1,00001499,00001499,16,01,0,T,003205784
```

The file above is sorted by column 2, I need to add the values of column 3 and as well for column 6,

If I take the data given above I need to break it up as follows and then do the calculations

The first column in the output will not be added together as this is a identifier. then all values in column 3 must be added together, followed by adding all values in column 6 for a output like this below

```
0000000000005   00000002  00005998

0000000000030   00000001  00003499

0000000000049   00000006  00017994

0000000000056   00000006  00005994

0000000000058   00000006  00008994
```

Where can I start?

Comment: A [mcve] detailing what you've tried, and what error you received (what went wrong) would be a great start.

Comment: @gravity, OP doesn't have any code yet, because of google.

Comment: Read the values into a 2d array the add together the appropriate parts of the array.  Remember to cast to a numeric datatype.  Try that and let us know where you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
List<string> allCsvLines = .... (fill it)

var result = allCsvLines.Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length >= 11)
    .Select(arr => new { Col2 = int.Parse(arr[1]), Col3 = int.Parse(arr[2]), Col6 = int.Parse(arr[5]), arr })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Col2) 
    .Select(g => new { Col2 = g.Key, Col3 = g.Sum(x => x.Col3), Col6 = g.Sum(x => x.Col6) });
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I've tested this and i get it to read my file correctly using 
            List<string> allCsvLines = new List<string>(filetoread);  now i get a error when I'm trying to write it to a file using  File.WriteAllLines that says it cant convert from anonymous type to string[].  is it the way that im trying to write to the file? as i have tried converting it to string as well then get the error cannot convert string to string[]

Comment: You want to write these three columns to the text file or all?

Comment: i want to write these 3 columns to text file

Comment: File.WriteAllLines(path, result.Select(x=> $"{x.Col2},{x.Col3},{x.Col6}"));